# Vagrant can't set locale to UTF-8 Postgres 8.4

Tags: bash, postgresql, encoding, utf-8, vagrant

I'm having a hard time setting up the locale of virtual box via vagrant precise64.

I tried this on my script:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PG_PROFILE="/home/vagrant/.profile"
echo "export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8" >> "$PG_PROFILE"
echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> "$PG_PROFILE"
```

on my bash script then trying to print out the locale which then correctly set.

I invoke those lines because I am going to install postgresql 8.4 on my virtual machine which was previously with LATIN1 encoding (by default). It was problem because I'm going to import sample data from a UTF-8 encoding thus it refrains from importing. But after invoking those lines, I still got a LATIN1 encoding on my postgresql. Please help

Comment: Can you try to run this query on your postgres installation: `SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';` also run this `SHOW client_encoding;` to see which type of encoding is being used, if I remember correctly you have to set a configuration variable in postgres for this.

Comment: postgres=# SET CLIENT_ENCODING TO 'UTF8';
=>SET
postgres=# SHOW client_encoding;
=>client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8
(1 row)

But when i tried \l it always have a LATIN1 encoding

Comment: @EndeNeu I had successfully set the locale to utf-8 correctly

Comment: Sorry this was my only guess.